# Remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop') is not working

Tags: functions, wysiwyg

I've tried disabling WP's auto-paragraph thingy using

`remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');`

but I am still getting my stuff wrapped in automatic `<p>` tags... What am I doing wrong?

Its at the bottom of a functions file. Its not in functions.php, but in a file that functions.php includes (and putting it in functions.php doesn't change the behaviour at all).

Update: 
`var_dump( $wp_filter['the_content'] );` outputs `NULL`. How can I test why this filter isn't being run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had same problem, fixed with css:

```
<style>
p:empty{
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This does not "fix the problem" when you have blocks of CSS or JS in the code, etc. This is not a solution, it's a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the TinyMCE Advanced plugin, try unchecking this advanced option:

> Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor

Unchecking that and using the `remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');` code in my functions.php did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is absolutely correct. You can try this snippet in template to ensure it is being removed:

```
var_dump( $wp_filter['the_content'] );
```

If it's not it may be that code never reaches your filter removal (`return` above it for example) or filter is re-added later by some other code.

Comment: or try changing the filter priority, default is 10

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba not sure what you mean? Priority should match exactly for `remove_filter()` to work.

Comment: yeah, but if you add a filter with priority 20, shouldn't you remove it with the same priority? maybe autop is added with a different priority...

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba I've checked the source and tested code, it is added without priority specified so default it is.

Comment: `var_dump( $wp_filter['the_content'] );` outputs `NULL`. I've tried grepping for `wpautop` but apparently none of the php files in wp-content contain this, apart from my line of code.

Comment: @Amanda If you call that line inside some function don't forget to `global $wp_filter;`. `wpautop` is setup in `wp-includes\default-filters.php`.

Comment: @Rarst - I stuck the var_dump inside header.php, just after the menu output...

Comment: @Rarst - doh, I had it outside the loop. It returns a bunch of stuff ... including `shortcode_unautop` but nothing else I could see about autop

Comment: Did you try lowering priority from 10 (default) to 1 as One Trick Pony suggested?

Comment: Remove shortcode_unautop, I've had this problem myself, it's the preg_replace in that filter that'll be returning NULL because of an error.

Comment: I agree with those who suggest changing the filter priority. Raise it to 11, or 20, or even 99, just to see if priority is in fact the issue.

Comment: I tried `remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop', 99);` and `remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop', 1);` - no change.

Comment: @Backie added `remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter ('the_content', 'shortcode_unautop');` - no change. Tried both with priorities 1 and 99 - no change.

Comment: None of this works for me. This is intensely frustrating. I need not to have <p> tags around scripts dynamically generated by a shortcode and therefore not enqueueable. D&$^&^*$T, Wordpress, stop changing my code! Why is it so hard to just say, "Hey, I'm the programmer, not you! Don't create code, *I'll* do it!"

Answer (score 0):

My problem was while developing a shortcode. Credits to Samuel Wood. See his advice here:

> Oh, and if you’re putting in shortcodes, use a shortcode block instead
> of typing them into a P block. Then you won’t have wrapper P tags.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpautop-not-working-on-wp_editor/

Comment: So, for those of us who don't use blocks.... ???